# Matlab: specify Neural Net with no hidden layer using built in functions

Tags: matlab, neural-network, regression

Most likely a trivial question...how can I create a neural network with no hidden layer for regression problems in Matlab using built in function (I understand this is the same as a multivariate linear regression).  My problem set has 5 predictors and one predictand.

I get an error when I try to fit a net with a hidden layer size of 0...i.e.

```
net=fitnet(0);
```

Error using fitnet (line 69)
Parameters.hiddenSizes contains a zero.

Second, if I try to call the net using the configure command I also get an error telling me it cannot configure the 'net' since it is a structure.

In short, how can I create a NET object with no hidden layer so that I can train and test it on a set of data predictor and predictand pairs similar to calling a net with a specified number of hidden nodes.

My version of Matlab is R2012a.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the `linearnet` function, it creates a very simple network of one layer with one neuron.

Comment: You could link some function reference to enhance your answer.